# Saving Parse objects from Arduino Yun

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, iot

I have followed the Parse quickstart guide for the Arduino Yun, and am getting the following response:

> Parse Starter Project
>
> Response for saving a TestObject:
>
> Test object id:

I have run the code from File > Examples > Bridge > WiFi status, which confirms I am connected to the wifi network. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: I think your arduino not connected to internet you can see it from http://arduino.local/ that say to you :  
There was a problem last time I tried configuring wireless network.
Check the following log for details of what went wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of Arduino 1.6.3 you will need to update the bridge library.

Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries -> Search for Bridge and update.

This should solve your problem as I was stuck in this scenario 2 days ago.

Comment: Make sure to restart the Arduino app afterwards as well.